# What should be DefaultLocation property of VS2010 setup to install application in C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, defaultlocation

I have to install windows service using Visual Studio. Target location for the install is handled by “DefaultLocation” property in Visual Studio setup project. I had used [AppDataFolder] tag to install the application.  As the result, it has been installed in “C:\Users[username]\AppData**Roaming**” folder. I can not figure out how to modify “DefaultLocation” property in such a way that application will be installed in C:\Users[username]\AppData**Local** folder. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 14):

Ok. I had found the answer. If you want to install your application into `C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local` folder, `[LocalAppDataFolder]` tag (value) should be used as DefaultLocation property.
Example: `[LocalAppDataFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]` 
See also: [LocalAppDataFolder property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369768%28VS.85%29.aspx)