# Appdata Roaming installation with Visual Studio deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

Im looking for the following information to decide whether to install my application in the [Local or Roaming folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915259/what-should-be-defaultlocation-property-of-vs2010-setup-to-install-application-i):

Using the Visual Studio setup project, say I [install my application into the Roaming folder](https://superuser.com/questions/150012/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-roaming-folders) (like Dropbox, for instance)

- Then is it not meant to be moved to other computers that the same domain user logs onto?
- From my limited testing, the **Roaming folders are not moved across?** e.g. I have a bunch of folders on Computer A that do not exist on Computer B for the same Active Directory user?
- If the folders do roam somehow, then **what happens to the Add Remove programs entry**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included some links in your post, but you didn't really read them. Perhaps this article will be more clear: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically, *Local* folder should contain files which will be used only on the current machine. In the *Roaming* folder you can install files which support user profile roaming (accessing the user profile from another machine).

So it all depends on what type of application you are installing:

- If it's contained and can function with only the user profile files, then you can use the *Roaming* folder.
- If it has dependencies specific to the current machine, use the *Local* folder.

Regarding Add or Remove programs, your application entry should be available for roaming profiles if its installed per-user.

Comment: i did read it, the issue is that in my testing the roaming doesnt actually work? i.e. i cannot access my folder under Roaming from another computer (with the same user). From the link you posted (a) it seems that either the size limit is quite small (what is the quota approximately?) or (b) [programmatic file-creation with this api is needed for roaming to work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than just copying files there with Windows Installer? just guesses...

Comment: if I get the folder / files to roam then wow that the Add or Remove Programs entry should roam with them! :)

Comment: Configuring a roaming user account seems like a different task. Try posting a question in the appropriate section.

Comment: oh, my mistake was to assume that all accounts are configured as roaming by default... thanks!